# Why is my post-animate function not being called?

Tags: jquery

I'm animating popups so that they fade and slide in simultaneously. I want to reset the position of the hidden popup once it's hidden so that the animation is the same every time.

When the element is rolled over, the popup slides down and fades in. When it's rolled out of, the popup slides down further and fades out, then when it's hidden, resets itself to its initial position.

Here's my code:

```
$('*:has(.rollover)').hover(function(){
  $('.rollover',this).fadeIn('fast').animate({
    'top' : '60px',
  }, {duration: 'fast', queue: false}, function() {});
},function(){
  $('.rollover',this).fadeOut('fast').animate({
    'top' : '70px',
  }, {duration: 'fast', queue: false}, function() {
    console.log("hello");
    $(this).css('top','50px');
  });
});
```

The problem is the last line where the `top` is reset is not being triggered, and neither is the log statement. Why is this?

Comment: Attaching an event handler to any element that has an element with the class .rollover probably means the event is attached to just about every element on the page, which sounds like a really bad idea. And you could simplify that with something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pmbr8/)

Comment: @adeneo I'm using `*:has(.rollover)` to select all elements that have a `.rollover` as an immediate child, is this wrong?

Comment: That selector will select any element which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector, not limited to immediate children. In other words, any element that has an element within it with the class .rollover, and that's probably just about every element on the page.

Comment: @adeneo I get it, I've replaced it with `$('.rollover').parent()` which works much better.

Answer (score 0):

My error was having:

```
, {duration: 'fast', queue: false}, function() {});
```

When I should have had:

```
, {duration: 'fast', queue: false, complete : function() {}});
```